# How to load a pretrained vgg model in distributed tensorflow model training scene like faster-rcnn?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I want to implements a faster-rcnn model using  distributed tensorflow, But I have difficult to load a pretrained vgg model,How to do it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [TensorFlow tutorial on retraining inception](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) is a good start to read. Then try to reproduce what it does starting from an already trained vgg model.

Comment: This is not a distributed version，supervisor.py   def _verify_setup(self):
    """Check that all is good.

    Raises:
      ValueError: If something is not good.
    """
    # Not running as chief means that replicas are used.
    # In that case all Variables must have their device set.
    if not self._is_chief:
      for op in self._graph.get_operations():
        if op.type in ["Variable", "VariableV2"] and not op.device:
          raise ValueError("When using replicas, all Variables must have "
                           "their device set: %s" % op)

Comment: Then set devices for all variable ops, or create your model with a replica device setter to do so automatically.

Comment: I have created model in block with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
            worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % args.task_index,
            cluster=cluster_spec)):. Do you have an example?

Comment: This should set devices for all variables. Are you sure no variables are being created outside this block? Optimizers' calls to minimize can create variables.

Comment: https://github.com/fanlu/Faster-RCNN_TF this is the github repo,Can you help me check it?The core code is here: tools/dist_train_net.py lib/networks/network.py lib/networks/VGGnet_train.py.

Comment: conv1_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/max: (Const): /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] conv1_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/max: (Const)/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
conv1_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/min: (Const): /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
this log print in chief worker node